# Windows 10 Windows 7 backup

Tags: windows-10, windows-7-backup

How would I go about in the Windows 10 "Back up and Restore (Windows 7)" in the Control Panel so that it DOESN'T store the disk label as well but just the drive letter like F: or G:.

Currently it stores "Samsung T1 (F:)" which is annoying because I have 2 SSD and alternate them regularly but to do that I have to change the properties  every time I run a backup.

**So how do I go about it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 backup is deprecated under Windows 10.
Microsoft has given up on it, just keeping it around for compatibility reasons,
but it won't be developed any more and might disappear some time in the future.

It is time to use a free third-party backup.
According to your needs, have a look at the products reviewed in the following:

- [Best Free File-Based Backup Program](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hard-drive-backup-program.htm)
- [Best Free Folder Synchronization Utility](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-folder-synchronization-utility.htm)
- [Best Free Drive Cloning Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm)